# Western Digital My Passport Essential drive asks for password after years of not needing to re-enter it

Tags: passwords

When I plug my Western Digital My Passport Essential it asks for the first time password (the [SmartWare](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11730) software Western Digital uses). I enter the password and it says that is incorrect.

It is asking for the password for the first time in ten years.

Comment: model of passport?

Comment: my passport essential 500 giga

Comment: So there is no model number on it?

Comment: WDBAAA5000ARD-00

Comment: Check my edited answer below, found a link to the firmware!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a know issue on older passport essentials with the Initio 1607E chip.

Probably cannot recover data but the article does not mention if you can after the firmware update to fix this issue.

> The password on a My Passport Essential has reset with no user input directing it to do so.

> This was a known issue with some older My Passport Essential drives with the Initio 1607E chip. If the voltage across the chip dropped below a certain level, the chip would enter an uncontrollable state, during which the DEK LBA (password field) could be overwritten. When this happened, the drive would overwrite the DEK LBA on its own, resulting in a password change.
> This could occur if the USB cable was loose or wiggled, or if the cable wasn't fully inserted into the USB slot on the computer or drive.

> A firmware update was released as a workaround for this issue. The firmware didn't allow the DEK to be overwritten unless the write command came from the appropriate function, preventing this issue from occurring.

https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4703/kw/my%20passport%20essential

EDIT: Found this link that works to get the firmware

https://web.archive.org/web/20170604013619/http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=262&lang=en

Comment: Firmware updates are dead links on that page I posted, I am trying to contact WD to see if firmware downloads is still available.

Comment: WD support is so horrible, only idiots on chat, said there is not firmware, no kidding the links are broken. Maybe you can have better luck getting the firmware for it.

Comment: I sent WD an email, maybe I will get a person with a brain.

Comment: Not sure if you have found the updater or not, I have a my passport ultra for mac, it somehow also have problem related to password. I found the firmware updater mentioned above but it did not support my model. You may try if you are still in need using terms `WD Universal Firmware Updater 4.0.1.4`. Since it is not official link, so you may examine and evaluate before making any update like opening the software, see what is it going to do, is it supporting your drive and so on. And then try to find related user comments in the web. Be cautious before updating a firmware. Good luck.